# redrawing is not working properly using invalidate

Tags: android, eclipse

We are doing chat application in android as final year project and new to android.I want to dynamically change the font style as user selects the option provided.So used sharedpreferences and invalidate function to redraw GUI. The following is my code snippet
     package com.kdr.star;

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Main extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences settings=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean first=settings.getBoolean("first", false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if(first)
 {

Typeface font=Typeface.MONOSPACE;
txt.setTypeface(font);
txt.Invalidate();
}



  Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent= new Intent(Main.this,Preference.class)   ;
startActivity(intent);
}
  });
  }
  }
```

This code works but partially. when the checkbox is selected the change does not appear at that instance while coming back. But if the application is closed and opened again the change will be seen. But i want the change to appear as soon as the checkbox is selected.Even the invalidate function is not helping out. Is there any other way to achieve it.Any guidance in this regard will be greatly appreciable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you put the invalidate in the onCreate(), I don't think it would redraw the changes.
Try put the invalidate() method in the onClickListener() or make a new method to refresh the image and call it on the listener.

Comment: In my project I use invalidate, but sometimes the drawn doesn't disapear. Why? I put it as the last code int onClickListener. Even if I duplicate invalidate, it happens not clear my shape. What would be the problem, so ?

Comment: It happens to me as well, but invalidate() is not the problem. Other code that you have might have been the problem, such as invalid loop or the drawn things are not pointed specifically.

Answer (score 1):

try postInvalidate() not invalidate().

the method invalidate() is not encouraged to use in non-UI thread.